# Vuepress deployment to Netfly Failed

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

Strictly followed the documentation here 
https://v1.vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/deploy.html#netlify
but build fails everytime. 
Site works greate on development, but each deployment build keeps failing.

Code base: https://github.com/MagicGary/DouglasCourses

Site setup in `package.json`:

```js
{
    "scripts": {
        "docs:dev": "vuepress dev docs",
        "docs:build": "vuepress build docs"
    }
}
```

Netfly Deployment Setup

```
Build Command: yarn docs:build or npm run docs:build
Publish directory: docs/.vuepress/dist
```

It says that `6:48:31 PM: sh: 1: vuepress: not found`, I'm farily new to deploying these, I think it is complaining that `vuepress` is not installed on the production server environment, but all I did was strictly following the documentation. The documentation does not mention anything else in deployment section besides this,

[image]

Did I miss something in the `config.js` of my project?

Netfly Deployment Error log

```
6:48:30 PM: Executing user command: npm run docs:build
6:48:31 PM: > @ docs:build /opt/build/repo
6:48:31 PM: > vuepress build docs
6:48:31 PM: sh: 1: vuepress: not found
6:48:31 PM: npm ERR!
6:48:31 PM:  code ELIFECYCLE
6:48:31 PM: npm
6:48:31 PM:  ERR! syscall spawn
6:48:31 PM: npm
6:48:31 PM: ERR!
6:48:31 PM: file sh
6:48:31 PM: npm
6:48:31 PM:  ERR! errno ENOENT
6:48:31 PM: npm ERR! @ docs:build: `vuepress build docs`
6:48:31 PM: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
6:48:31 PM: npm
6:48:31 PM:  ERR!
6:48:31 PM: npm
6:48:31 PM:  ERR!
6:48:31 PM:  Failed at the @ docs:build script.
6:48:31 PM: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
6:48:31 PM: npm
6:48:31 PM:  ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
6:48:31 PM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2020-01-15T02_48_31_298Z-debug.log
6:48:31 PM: Skipping functions preparation step: no functions directory set
6:48:31 PM: Caching artifacts
6:48:31 PM: Started saving node modules
6:48:31 PM: Finished saving node modules
6:48:31 PM: Started saving pip cache
6:48:31 PM: Finished saving pip cache
6:48:31 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
6:48:31 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
6:48:31 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
6:48:31 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
6:48:31 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
6:48:31 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
6:48:31 PM: Started saving go dependencies
6:48:31 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
6:48:33 PM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
6:48:33 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
6:48:33 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
6:48:34 PM: Finished processing build request in 14.167417237s
```

Comment: Hi, haven't had time to dig deep into it. But the official documentation site is now https://vuepress.vuejs.org

Answer (score 1):

per the documentation on the link you sent, you must have vuepress installed as a local dependency

```
You are placing your docs inside the docs directory of your project;
You are using the default build output location (.vuepress/dist);
VuePress is installed as a local dependency in your project, and you have setup the following npm
```

you can follow the official documentation on how to add vuepress as a local dependency using the following link (which also mentions netlify)

https://v1.vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/getting-started.html#inside-an-existing-project

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that and used ``npm install`` to install it locally. It builds successfully, but this is what it looks like https://romantic-goodall-9c1d2d.netlify.com/

Comment: and similarly when i deployed it to heroku, it says ``npm ERR! missing script: start``

Comment: @BaoYutong鲍昱彤 can you put the exact npm command that you used? it must be npm install -D vuepress and not just npm install vuepress. Regarding the second error I'm guessing that in your scripts setup you would need to add "docs:start"

Comment: npm install -D vuepress

Comment: Pls double-check your `base` setting at https://vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#base